# put two divs on same line using margin

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the divs `div.mes` and `div.vazio` on same line. If I remove the margin from two divs (`QuadroPrincipal` and `ul_mes`) I get the result I want.

The problem is that I need divs `mes` and `vazio` on same line keeping the margins on elements `quadroPrincipal` and `ul_mes`.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/4Zjx8/5/

I want to build this example:

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about **not** making `.mes`'s width 100%? Also, you need to specify what behaviour you need; should `.vazio` be displayed partially? Should `.mes` give way and become less wide? Do you actually need percentages? Is the container a fixed width so the widths in the example/fiddle would always be some known value? (e.g. if container width = 1000 and `.foo` would be 75% it would always be 750px (exluding margins etc.)).

Comment: .vazio should be displayed totally and mes should expand to all remaining space. As I'm building a liquid layout, I need a fixed width for .vazio and a percent for mes. the width is not fixed. I've put on jfiddle my real code. I just removed the code that doesn't affect this example.

Comment: In that case, make it [position: absolute; right: 0](http://jsfiddle.net/4Zjx8/7/). Make sure you understand the different methods of [positioning](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101) and what [floats](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-floats-101) do etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, give div#ListaEventosPorMes a width.

Then float:left .mes and .vazio and give each of those a width that adds up to less than the width of the div.

Comment: I can't give a fixed width. my layout is liquid and I'm using percentage.